# There is a bluetooth audio delay on my Mid 2014 Mac on Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, mojave, bluetooth

Whenever I connect my bluetooth earbuds to my Mac, there is a noticeable audio lag when watching videos. How do I solve this. I use my earbuds with my Android phone and they work perfectly.

Comment: My understanding is Apple do this deliberately, on all Macs, on all bluetooth devices, so that when you stream video to an external device, the inherent video delay matches the audio delay.  It's stupid.  Apple and bluetooth is a marriage made in hell.

Answer (score 0):

Allegedly, [Tooth Fairy](https://c-command.com/toothfairy/) cures all manner of Bluetooth woes.

Comment: If some answer happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers. https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior Please dont post link only answers, Tell us what it does, prices if any, and whether you're linked to the product or not.

Comment: I don't see anywhere on the website that says it can fix lag issues.